# Python2: Regex pattern to match all names

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

Below are the files in a folder and wanted to write a regex pattern to match all the filenames
and separate it like into 4 groups like

Groups:

1. Text before date pattern
2. Date Pattern
3. Text after date pattern
4. Extension (any or no extension)

Names:

```
XYZ_XY__T_20180808_88
GYG_20180813.csv
JENNY_BH_COSTUMES_T_20180808_88.csv
JKS9KS9_DDD_20180809_2.txt
AMY_BH_MAKEUP_T_20180808_88.dat
UUB-134941099-00002531-003_20180814
usa-Nasa_Y_20180806_01.csv
usa-Tpkyo-HHDY_Y_20180806_01.csv
```

Tried this -

```
(\w+)(-?)_(\d{4}\d{2}\d{2})(\w+)?(\.csv|\.dat|\.txt)?
```

but doesn't seem to work. How to go about this?

Comment: What exactly do you want with the text before/after the dashes and underscores? Do you want *all* text before the date pattern to be captured in a group, or only word characters, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to capture *all* the text before the date substring regardless, it looks like all you have to do is include dashes and underscores in the initial group: `([\w-_]+)` (and drop the following group that captures an optional standalone dash):

You may also use `^` and `$` to ensure that matches span the entire line:

```
^([\w-_]+)(\d{4}\d{2}\d{2})(\w+)?(\.csv|\.dat|\.txt)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/M5kIo6/1